# How to fade in/out the background color of a tableviewcell with Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicolor

I have a tableview and when I receive a message it reloads and then I want the cell that received the message to change its background color for a second and then change back to previous color (with or without fade in/out)

I know which cell received the message with that code:

```
    if changeCell == indexPath.row { 

         cell.viewCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red 

    }
```

viewCell Is a view I put in cell to change the background color of the cell more easily

I search a lot to find it out but every solution started with `UIView.animate`.... when I put it it changed the color of the view outside my tableview

Comment: Are you using xcode 8 and swift 3.0 ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya yes

Answer (score 4):

The UIView animate family of methods is what you want.

```
    let oldColor = cell.viewCell.backgroundColor
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        cell.viewCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }, completion: { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                cell.viewCell.backgroundColor = oldColor
            }
    })
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but all cells are fading in/out

Answer (score 3):

Add these options for the animation:

- UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve
- UIViewAnimationOptions.allowAnimatedContent

Example:

```
fileprivate var color1 = UIColor.clear
fileprivate var color2 = UIColor.red
fileprivate func animateCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve, .allowAnimatedContent], animations: {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = self.color2
    }) { (_) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = self.color1
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a UIImageView in the cell and setting the alpha of that. I couldn't get backgroundColor to animate.